# How to determine which city a given long and latitude points represent?

Tags: geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

I'm currently using a very large geo-ip database that i've built as a mixture from many freeware sites.

The problem is - the mapping of all those database is :  map: (ip) -> (latitude,long)

I'm looking for a way that will deduce the location of those latitude and long points by resolution of a city and if possible - offline.

thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you are going to do geocoding, you may find it  useful to map to zipcode or metropolitan statistical area (if you're in the US; similar ideas for other countries), so that you can then reference demographic information.  However, be careful that your IP -> (lat, long) database is accurate enough to support this granularity of mapping.  It's usually not.

Comment: @iterator - I'm using what there is freely on the net.I'm aware of that itsnot that accurate but thats what i've got

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Google Geocoding http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

to do it offline, you'll need a database of long/lat coordinates, such as this: http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities

then to match the long/lat to the cities, you'll have to build an algorithm which narrows it down to within a margin of error.

a brute-force method might be to measure the distance by using pythagoras' theorem, but that would rapidly kill your CPU. a better way may be to start by excluding results that are 1 or more above or below your target lat/long, then do your measurements on the remaining results.

Answer (score 0):

you can get city and region lat/lon information from [citycsv.com](http://citycsv.com) if you really need your info offline. It would be easy to query the data for lat/lon and get a city or region back. However as stated google would be able to take a lot of overhead off your hands with their online geocoding tools.

you could run google's geocode in burst-mode (2.500 max per day) through a cron job and fill up your offline database over the course of ....